# How do I 410 a pattern of toxic Prestashop URLS?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop, url-routing, http-status-code-410

I've been trying to 410 a pattern of a few thousands toxics URLS that got indexed by Google for one of my clients. I want every urls of the website that contain `?%` to send a 410 response code so they got de-indexed.

Example of an URL :

```
https://www.example.com/fr/promotions?%25252525253Bid_lang=6&p=6
```

I've tried to put this in the `.htaccess`, above the If module section, as I found on another thread here, but it didn't work, any ideas ?

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]shop($|/) - [G]
```

Comment: "I found on another thread" - I'm curious what other "thread" this was from? The code you posted would seem to be unrelated to what you are trying to do and is more likely to cause damage?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want every urls of the website that contain ?% to send a 410 response code

Using mod_rewrite at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Send 410 for any URL where the query string starts with "%"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^%
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```